# Failed to resolve dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I am trying to add user auth ability in my app with FirebaseUI for Android, and since I've added this two dependencies for authentication in my gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.1.1'
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is there any compatibility issue between this dependencies?

Comment: have you tried to install the repositories as written in the error?

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUI version 2.1.1 has transitive dependencies on Support Lib version 25.4.0.  The [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies) contains this important configuration note:

> NOTE : Starting version 25.4.0, support libraries are now available
>   through Google's Maven repository, so ensure that you have that added
>   to your project's repositories.
>
> Open the build.gradle file for your project and modify it as
>   following,

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

For consistency with FirebaseUI change your dependencies to use version 25.4.0 of the Suppport Library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
```